# Data loosing when closing the drools kiesession with scala

Tags: scala, drools, kie

I have a application which is created with KieSession state-full object and its processing the rules, and result generated into the Iterator. But When I am trying to return the results after disposing the kiesession I am facing issues.

```
def ruleExucetion[T](originalData: Iterator[T], drtFile: String ): Iterator[T] = {
 val kSession = getKieSession(drtFile)
 val processedData = getDataModels(kSession, originalData)
 // processedData.size ==> printing the value, but after dispose function, I lost the Iterator data.
 kSession.dispose()
 return processedData
}
```

Here how can i dispose/close the connection without loosing the `processedData`. can we set (scala)eager-loading for above Iterator?

EDITED:

```
def getDataModels[T](kSession: KieSession, originalData: Iterator[T]): Iterator[T] = {
   val dataModels = originalData.map(dataModel => {
   kSession.insert(dataModel)
   dataModel
  })
  kSession.fireAllRules()
  return dataModels
}
```

Below is the error Stake trace :-

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception:       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal method call. This session was previously disposed.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal method call. This session was previously disposed.
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.checkAlive(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1255)
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.insert(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1493)
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.insert(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1454)
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.insert(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1448)
at com.giri.rules.Run$$anonfun$1.apply(Run.scala:36)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.size(TraversableOnce.scala:107)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.size(Iterator.scala:1336)
```

Comment: what issues are you facing? What connection are you losing?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti : Yes, facing connection failure issues with kiesession. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal method call. This session was previously disposed.`

Comment: without a stacktrace and without knowing what your `getDataModels()` method is doing, is really hard to help you.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti I added stack-trace details